# How to convert a Json formatted values in Athena table to clean table format?

Tags: sql, json, database, amazon-athena

I have a table which looks like below . This data comes from a json file which is placed in an s3 bucket.The table is created by the AWS crawler.

| col0 | col1 |
| --- | --- |
| {"Serial No":"1" | "Status":"PASS"} |
| {"Serial No":"2" | "Status":"FAIL"} |

What I am trying to achieve is a table which looks like below ,basically the key should become the column name and value as the record. Note I have multiple columns in my case:

| Serial No | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | PASS |
| 2 | FAIL |

I tried openjson , UNNEST but nothing worked. I need to have an SQL which could go through this table and dynamically return return in the desired format . I cannot put values and then reformat. As this SQL will be run in Grafana everyday automatically and the dashboard will show results. So there is no scope of hardcoding any value

Comment: Is the json really split into 2 different columns like that in col0 and col1?  Neither of those are valid json.    If it is consistently like that you would have to concat the columns together with a comma and then you could use json_extract_scalar.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is assuming the original json is:

```
{
  "Serial No": "1",
  "Status": "PASS"
}
```

but the crawler split the data on the comma into 2 different columns.

Base on your sample I'll also assume that is consistent in your data.

You could [concat](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/concatenating-strings-and-arrays.html) the columns and then use [json_extract_scalar](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/extracting-data-from-JSON.html).

Here is a working example to see how that works:

```
select
    json_extract_scalar(concat(col1, ',', col2), '$["Serial No"]') as "Serial No",
    json_extract_scalar(concat(col1, ',', col2), '$.Status') as "Status"
from (
        VALUES('{"Serial No":"1"', '"Status":"PASS"}'),
            ('{"Serial No":"2"', '"Status":"FAIL"}')
    ) as test_data(col1, col2)
```

Giving the results of:

[image]